# How create one autonumeric properties from a linq select

Tags: c#, linq

I want create a `List<myItem>` from a single string to fill the `myValue` property.

**string:**

```
"233 984 5 66 304 219 277 790"
```

**class:**

```
public class myItem
{
    public long ID;      // autonumeric id go here
    public long myValue; // string values go here
    public string otherProperties; //I will fill later from other source
}
```

I can read the string, split using space and parse to `long[]`:

```
 string line1 = "233 984 5 66 304 219 277 790";
 string[] words = line1.Split(' ');
 long[] myValues = Array.ConvertAll(words, s => long.Parse(s));
```

But dont know how create the `List<myItem>`

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for.  The data you have here doesn't even remotely match the target structure.

Comment: I also don't get what you want. if you want to send some data somewhere, you need to do it using something like JSON which is very easy.

Comment: @DavidL As you can see I have the array of integer. I want a `List<myItem>` with those `long` from `myValues`, and one `ID` autonumeric property.

Comment: Keep in mind that the expression *autonumeric property* is a database term that is not clear in the context of C#, and that you would need to explain in more detail. Fortunately, it seems like some understood your intent and have given you good answers already.

Comment: @sstan yes, but looks like other didnt like my question at all. :(

Comment: @AshkanSirous I want create a `list<myItem>` using the values from a string, hope after the edit is more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var list = 
    line1.Split(' ').
    Select((word, ix) => new myItem() { 
        ID = ix, 
        myValue = long.Parse(word) 
    }).
    ToList();
```

Comment: I know you can choose any name for your variable `(word, ix)` but how Linq know `word` is the result from the split and `ix` is the index?

Comment: The first argument is always the value, and the second is always the index. See the [docs link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that @Habib linked in his answer.

Comment: I actually did upvote, because I don't think your question is *that* bad, but please do not beg for upvotes.

Comment: Sorry for that, isnt really for the votes or the points, is to right the wrong, When you have OCD is hard to let it go And those negatives will be on my mind for a long time :/. I could delete the question and forget about it, but I think your answer are worth to keep.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

- Split your string with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` so that if there are multiple spaces between words, they could be ignored.
- Use `IEnumerable<T>.Select` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which supports index
- Project that output to your class

Code:

```
List<myItem> list = line1.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select((r, i) => new { Index = i, Value = r })
    .Select(t => new myItem
    {
        ID = t.Index,
        myValue = long.Parse(t.Value),
    }).ToList();
```

*I should also add that the above could have been done by the single `Select` with the index overload and instead of selecting anonymous type with `Index` and `Value` field, the index and value could be projected to `myValues` class.*

Comment: @sstan, one would have done it. , Just wanted to be explicit about the intent of using index overload.

Comment: Thanks Habib, lucky you understand my question. btw was my question so bad? Please, can you add the one select version too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I believe the *one select* version Habib is referring to is the same as the code in my answer.

Comment: Sorry Habib. @Blorgbeard beat you for half minute.